# How to clear inputs (reset forms) after submitting

Tags: angular, typescript

I am starting to program angular and I do not understand how I can clear the inputs after clicking a submit button.

Can anyone explain to me a simple procedure of being able to clear / reset the inputs / forms after clicking the submit button? Is there a way to put any validator in one of the fields?

I've seen some topics on the subject, but could not understand the logic.

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ccfeas?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**HTML**

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Email address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1">
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label>Adress</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1">
  </div>
   <div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlInput1">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleFormControlTextarea1">Example textarea</label>
    <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
  <button type="submit" (click)="clearforms()">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to start using an angular form in the first place. Currently, you're not. You just have inputs that Angular doesn't care about. Read the guide: https://angular.io/guide/forms-overview

Comment: Please include all necessary code in the question itself, not only on an external site.

Answer (score 1):

I'd strongly recommend following the first commenter's advice.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-sbjyrc?file=src/app/app.component.html) is a working example which makes use of **Template Driven Forms**, which basically represents a declarative way to build your form tree.

If you're dealing with more dynamic stuff, you should consider using **Reactive Forms**, it will give you much more control on the situation.

You can also provide validators. You can do this either through some directives, or, especially when using Reactive Forms, through the [Validators](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators) object.

For instance, here's how you'd use an **email validator** as a directive:

```html
<input ngModel name="email" email>
```

[Here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/validators.ts) is a file that contains all the validators which are available as directives.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help !!